# RecentlyViewed causes non-selective query error when run from a screen flow

Tags: soql, visual-workflow, invocable-method, recentlyviewed

I have a screen flow that calls an invocable apex method containing the query:

```
 List<RecentlyViewed> viewedRecords = [SELECT Id , Name , Type , LastViewedDate 
        FROM RecentlyViewed WHERE LastViewedDate =TODAY Order By LastViewedDate Desc 
        LIMIT 5 ];
```

which results in the error:`FLOW_ELEMENT_ERROR An Apex error occurred: System.QueryException: Non-selective query against large object type (more than 200000 rows).`

The method works perfectly when called from anonymous apex and unit test. Even when I remove the WHERE clause completely in the dev console, it only returns 300 records.

I understand this object is designed to only have access the running user's recently viewed records but it looks like there is a possible data leak in flow context. I have made sure to check that the flow runs as the running user and the apex class is "With Sharing". I'm not sure how to make the query any more selective as it doesn't look like there are any sort of "CreatedDateById" fields for RecentlyViewed.

Comment: I too have an invocable method that results in a QueryException because of a non-selective query, but only when called from Flow. I can run the method via anonymous apex fine. Maybe invoking via Flow is similar to invoking via Trigger, which restricts non-selective queries, per this article? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000333150&type=1&mode=1